# below excel formula having issue in last column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have added a excel formula below in excel Q column.
 Getting error for last 3 rows,
 any effort would be appreciated.
thanks

```
   B                     Q
EutranCellFDDId         afterformula
CLL03682_7A_1              7
CLL03682_7B_1               7
CLL03682_7C_1               7
CLL03682_2A_1           CLL03682_2A_1
CLL03682_2B_1           CLL03682_2B_1
CLL03682_2C_1           CLL03682_2C_1
CLL03682_9A_1           CLL03682_9A_1
CLL03682_9B_1           CLL03682_9B_1
CLL03682_9C_1           CLL03682_9C_1
CLL03682_3A_1           CLL03682_3A_1
CLL03682_3B_1           CLL03682_3B_1
CLL03682_3C_1           CLL03682_3C_1
CLL03682_2A_2           CLL03682_2A_2
CLL03682_2B_2           CLL03682_2B_2
CLL03682_2C_2           CLL03682_2C_2
CLL03682_7A_3_F         #VALUE!
CLL03682_7B_3_F         #VALUE!
CLL03682_7C_3_F         #VALUE!


=IF(OR((AND(RIGHT(B2,1)="F",VALUE(MID(B2,10,1))=7)),
       (AND(VALUE(RIGHT(B2,1))=1,VALUE(MID(B2,10,1))=7)))
   ,MID(B2,10,1)
   ,B2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpler:

```
=IF( 
     AND( MID(B2,10,1)="7", OR(RIGHT(B2,1)="F", RIGHT(B2,1)="1") ),
     MID(B2,10,1),
     B2
    )
```